# What do the red exclamation mark icons in front of references mean in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, icons

In Visual Studio 2010 project property pages, if I select Common Properties and Framework and References for a C++ project, I can see all the references from a project.

They usually have this icon: [image: normal reference]
Sometimes, though, some references appear as this: [image: red exclamation mark]

I tried to google it or find any documentation about it in the msdn documentation about references, but cannot find anything related to this. Does someone know about this? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?

Answer (score 6):

This happens also if you had VS2010 SP1 and then install .net 4.5. They changed the handling of this in a way that causes problem in VS2010. (.net 4.5 is installed with VS2012)

Comment: The questioner was asking about native unmanaged references, not .NET references.

Comment: You can see details of this at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2734667.  It states "...references to native VC++ projects are shown in the UI as unresolved (on the “Framework and References” property page). This is indicated by a red exclamation point icon next to the reference name as well as a missing Full Path property."

Answer (score 4):

I believe it is because the referenced assembly is a different version than your target application.  I receive the same thing if I reference a .net 4.0 assembly from a .net 3.5 project.

Comment: The questioner was asking about native unmanaged references, not .NET references.